# sensor selection for temperature and humidity readings

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

do anyone help me regarding selecting the sensor, digital temp and humidity in one module and have digital output and one pin connected to micro controller renesas V850 . I have only 3 pins unused. any suggestions please..

Answer (score 1):

The DHT22 would work:
http://www.adafruit.com/products/385

But with three pins on your MCU you could bit bang yourself an I2C bus to connect many other sensors.

Comment: I have 4 digital I/O pins unused and can I apply I2C or SPI protocol with those pins.? if yes how ?  or I need another pins? for these types of communication.which communication protocol can I use for DHT22.?

Comment: This is bit banging: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging

Comment: The DHT22 requires no ordinary serial protocol. It uses a pulse timing scheme. Check the datasheet on the page I linked o.

Comment: but I have one more question that already my controller has a lot of applications if I connect 4 DHT22 sensors to the 4 Digital I/O pins and communicate in pulse scheme. does it distrubs any other work done by controller.??

Comment: You say thanks by selecting my answer... ;) The pulse scheme will probably have an impact on your other code execution.